# (iOS) iPad app Crashing Randomly on Start

Tags: ios, ipad, crash

I have an iPad app out in the field (enterprise distribution) that randomly stopped working (after about 150 uses). It loads the black screen like its about to open but then flashes back to the main screen.

- No other apps are installed on the iPad.
- iPad is not jailbroken.
- iPad software has not been updated since install.

The app remains in the running list, but will not open. After resetting the iPad and reinstalling the app, it runs fine again. The crash report is as follows:

```
Incident Identifier: 97E6C3AC-0A3F-4D5A-9316-14361B8875C8
CrashReporter Key:   acbe2088ab1236c4f317ec9e0fb85d4a9d7b5b3a
Hardware Model:      iPad1,1
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-08-05 14:52:54.380 -0400
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3.2 (8H7)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   dyld                            0x2fe0124a dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*) + 446
1   dyld                            0x2fe01058 _dyld_start + 48

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000009      r2: 0x00000009      r3: 0x0004a000
    r4: 0x0004a01c    r5: 0x00000000      r6: 0x00000005      r7: 0x2fe48a18
    r8: 0x2fe6f18c    r9: 0x2fe96964     r10: 0x2fe494f4     r11: 0x00049000
    ip: 0x2fe96984    sp: 0x2fe489d0      lr: 0x2fe489ac      pc: 0x2fe4a24a
  cpsr: 0x60000030

Binary Images:
0x2fe49000 - 0x2fe6efff  dyld armv7  <bb9bfc7d242331d29a79adf7ef7aaa18> /usr/lib/dyld
```

This is all the information the report contains.

We've never been able to reproduce the crash on the simulator.

Any ideas? Can't send this back out until we make sure the error is fixed. Thanks,

Comment: This sounds exactly like what happens when a provisioning profile has expired. I have no experience with enterprise distribution, but are you sure the provisioning profiles are installed correctly?

Comment: I totally agree, however it only happens occasionally and the provisioning profile on the device still reads as Verified.

Comment: We had the same problem with our application, and in the end i think it was a problem with the provisioning profiles (maybe a conflict with older ones). Because we couldn't use XCODE to connect to the device, the client used iPhoneConfigurationUtility to remove all profiles and install the application cleanly. After this... it worked.

Comment: Removing expired and invalid profiles from the device usually magically helps.

Comment: @JJ. ever found a solution to this problem?

Comment: Are you using Core Data? I recently came across this problem and it turned out the Sqlite database used Core Data was corrupt.

Answer (score 1):

The system is probably killing the app because the provisioning profile has expired. If you can get access to the old app (e.g. by syncing with iTunes and then doing `Reveal in Finder` on the app) then you can find the provisioning profile inside the app as `embedded.mobileprovision` which you can inspect to determine if it has expired.

Answer (score 0):

Check your startup sequence carefully.  Perhaps some config file you are reading is corrupt or cannot be deserialized to a data structure (e.g., NSDictionary) properly.

I've had this happen to me.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue today and finally I adjust the provisioning profile of my app then the strange crash disappeared.
So you can try to this method to solve the problem.
PS:My crash log is same as the JJ's
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

1.make sure the device identifier key has been added in your IDP's distribution profile,
2.download that profile and drop on to Xcode
3.clean, build/archive you app project
4.Give users a URL to download(install) that mobileprofile file
5.enterprise distribution you app.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to your project setting  not just armv7 but armv6 also.

Answer (score 0):

Does it occur always after 150  or more uses?
If yes then checkout what all parameters get affected when it's used for large number of time.
I had faced similar problem but my app was using core data.**I was saving some value and by mistake I had set the type to INT 16. and it used to crash whenever value passes 2^15 for ios 5 and above.**
Secondly , are you able to re-start app after quitting the app from background or you have to delete the app and re-install it to fix the problem?